# Futuristic prison escape movie where convicts wear linked collars

Tags: story-identification, movie

In this movie, convicts are forced to wear collars linked to other convicts (they don't know which ones), and if one prisoner moves too far from the other, both collars explode. Two prisoners figure out their collars are linked to each other and escape by staying close together. One was played by Rutger Hauer, and the other by a woman.

Comment: Deadlocked: Escape from Zone 14 (TV Movie 1995)

Comment: @BatiRamirez- the movie I was looking for was before that- also it was made for theaters (I think) and I don't think Rutger Hauer was in your suggestion.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is *[Wedlock](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103239/)* (1991), starring Hauer and Mimi Rogers.  It was originally titled "Deadlock," and that name was used in a lot of promotional material (such as the trailer below); however, I do not think the "Deadlock" name was used in any actual prints of the film.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedlock_(film)):

> After stealing diamonds in a robbery, diamond thief Frank Warren is betrayed by his best friend Sam and his fiancée Noelle, who turns him into the authorities. Frank is sentenced to 12 years imprisonment at Camp Holliday, an experimental prison where each convict is given an electronic collar containing an explosive device which is electronically connected to another inmate. If any inmate tries to escape from Camp Holliday and is separated from the collar-mate by more than 100 yards, their collars will explode. Frank learns the inmate he is connected to is Tracey Rigg and Tracey and Frank both escape with their collars intact. On the run from the authorities, Tracey and Frank find they are being pursued by Sam and Noelle, believing Frank will lead them to the diamonds, which he has hidden. Can Frank and Tracey get to the diamonds without separating from each other more than 100 yards?

Comment: I saw it on VHS in the UK and I think it was called Deadlock on the box but I might be misremembering.